# Nokogiri and XML Formatting When Inserting Tags

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'd like to use Nokogiri to insert nodes into an XML document. Nokogiri uses the `Nokogiri::XML::Builder` class to insert or create new XML.

If I create XML using the `new` method, I'm able to create nice, formatted XML:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.product {
    xml.test "hi"
  }
end

puts builder
```

outputs the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<product>
  <test>hi</test>
</product>
```

That's great, *but* what I want to do is add the above XML to an existing document, not create a new document. According to the Nokogiri documentation, this can be done by using the Builder's `with` method, like so:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(document.at('products')) do |xml|
  xml.product {
    xml.test "hi"
  }
end

puts builder
```

When I do this, however, the XML all gets put into a single line with no indentation. It looks like this:

```
<products><product><test>hi</test></product></products>
```

Am I missing something to get it to format correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60366633/128421 is useful too. Using a string you can make the node, and even its children, look just as you'd want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer in the Nokogiri mailing list:

> In XML, whitespace can be considered
>   meaningful.  If you parse a document
>   that contains whitespace nodes,
>   libxml2 will assume that whitespace
>   nodes are meaningful and will not
>   insert them for you.
>
> You can tell libxml2 that whitespace
>   is not meaningful by passing the
>   "noblanks" flag to the parser.  To
>   demonstrate, here is an example that
>   reproduces your error, then does what
>   you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'
def build_from node
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(node) do|xml|
    xml.hello do
      xml.world
    end
  end
end

xml = DATA.read
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts build_from(doc.at('bar')).to_xml
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml) { |x| x.noblanks }
puts build_from(doc.at('bar')).to_xml
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar>
      <baz />
    </bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

Comment: I was looking for a flag the other day when I saw your question, but got distracted shaving a yak. +1 to you for finding the answer and posting it, and +1 to Nokogiri for rocking.

Comment: understandable. those yaks don't shave themselves (yet).

Comment: Note that under Ruby 1.9 you can specify the single noblanks flag in a slightly more terse manner: `doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml,&:noblanks)`

Comment: The &:noblanks did the trick. In the first build_from(doc.at('bar')).to_xml , the error is produced; but in the second build_from(doc.at('bar')).to_xml, the output is well formatted