# How to create a Nokogiri::XML::Node from Nokogiri::XML::Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I need to replace a node in a document with new HTML I'm creating.

The class of the node I have to replace is:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Node
```

I create my fragment using the Nokogiri Builder:

```
new_node = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.table('border' => '1', 'cellpadding' => '1', 'cellspacing' => '1') {
    xml.thead {
      xml.tr {
        battery_test[0..4].each do |head|
          xml.th_ head["inputValue"]
        end
      }
    }
    xml.tbody {
      battery_test.drop(5).each_slice(5) do |row|
        xml.tr {
          row.each do |item|
            xml.td_ item["inputValue"]
          end
        }
      end
    }
  }
end
```

But the class of `new_node` is `Nokogiri::XML::Builder`.

How can I replace my Nokogiri::XML::Node with the fragment I create with the builder?

Comment: Please see "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need the smallest runnable code that duplicates the along with the desired output in the question itself. Without that we're shooting in the dark. For instance, what is `battery_test`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Builder to create nodes. Nokogiri allows several ways of defining them. Your question isn't asked well as it's missing essential information, but this will get you started:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
# >>   <body>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

I can add a table using a string containing the HTML:

```
body = doc.at('body')
body.inner_html = "<table><tbody><tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></tbody></table>"

puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
# >>   <body><table><tbody><tr>
# >> <td>foo</td>
# >> <td>bar</td>
# >> </tr></tbody></table></body>
# >> </html>
```

Modify the string generation to contain the HTML you need, let Nokogiri do the heavy lifting, and you're done. It's easier to read and maintain.

[`inner_html=`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#inner_html=-instance_method) is defined as:

> `inner_html=(node_or_tags)`

`node_or_tags` means you can pass a node created using Builder, snipped from some other place in the DOM, or a string containing the markup.

Similarly:

```
table = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('table', doc)
table.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element

table.add_child('<tbody><tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></tbody>')
body = doc.at('body')
body.inner_html = table

puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
# >>   <body><table><tbody><tr>
# >> <td>foo</td>
# >> <td>bar</td>
# >> </tr></tbody></table></body>
# >> </html>
```

Note that `table` is a `Nokogiri::XML::Element`. HTML nodes are a subclass of XML nodes so don't let that confuse you.

The tutorials are good starting points for trying anything with Nokogiri. In this case "[Modifying an HTML / XML Document](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html)" is useful. Also the "[Cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet)" is chock-full of goodness. Finally, "[Questions tagged [nokogiri]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nokogiri?sort=votes)" reveals all the top questions on Stack Overflow.